# Help with deciding amplifying factor, small circuit

Tags: amplifier, circuit-analysis, common-emitter

[image: Small signal model]

Hi,

To decide the amplifying factor \$A\$ of the circuit above I take \$A=U_{out} /U_{in}\$.

\$U_{out}\$ and \$U_{in}\$ is derived like this:

\$U_{out}=\frac{h_{21}I_B}{1/R_c+1/R_3}\$ (1)

\$U_{in}=U_{GS1}+I_Bh_{11}+(I_B+h_{21}I_B)R_E\$ (2)

Now I need one final independent equation for \$I_B\$.

\$I_B=\frac{R_2 g_m U_{GS1}}{R_2+h_{11}+R_E}\$ (3)

Am I thinking correct or are the derivations wrong? I just need help with the derivations of these thre expressions. The small signal model is assumed to be correct.

Comment: you can check by making a simulation

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the current divider (eqn 3), because \$\small h_{11}\$ is not in series with \$\small R_E\$.

The third independent equation must include \$\small R_2\$ as it hasn't appeared in (1) and (2), hence: \$\small U_{in}=U_{GS1}+(g_mU_{GS1}-I_B)R_2\$ will do the job.